# Increasing JVM memory in solr cloud node

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I am running solr in cloud mode, but since i have large index, my solr servers are getting switched off i need to increase the jvm memory for the solr node, kindly help me how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

The reference guide [has a page on JVM settings that are relevant](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/jvm-settings.html) for Solr.

> The maximum heap size, set with -Xmx, is more critical. If the memory heap grows to this size, object creation may begin to fail and throw OutOfMemoryException. Setting this limit too low can cause spurious errors in your application, but setting it too high can be detrimental as well.

But .. if your server is disappearing and not giving OOM errors, that sounds like your process is being OOM killed by the underlying operating system. Check syslog (if you're on linux) for messages about the process being terminated.

You [can change the settings by defining](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/taking-solr-to-production.html#TakingSolrtoProduction-MemoryandGCSettings) the `SOLR_JAVA_MEM` setting:

> `SOLR_JAVA_MEM="-Xms10g -Xmx10g"`